# Passing f:atrribute to a nested composition component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I have two nested composite components such as:

```
<my:inputContainer>
    <my:input/>
</my:inputContainer>
```

And I need to pass a **f:attribute** to **my:input** in order to get it back in its validator:

```
<my:inputContainer>
    <my:input>
        <f:attribute name="attr" value="any value"/>
    </my:input>
</my:inputConainer>
```

But when I try to retrieve the attribute value in validator from **component.getAttributes()** it doesn't exist.

My components are defined basically this way:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <my:input name="input1"/>
    <my:input name="input2">
        <f:attribute name="input1Value" value="#{cc.attrs.input1Value}"/>
        <f:validator validatorId="myInputValidator" for="inputText"/>      
    </my:input>
</cc:implementation>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that's not possible. **cc:insertChildren** does not render **f:attribute**. If you want to pass a **f:attribute** from one component to another, you must define **cc:attribute** in **cc:interface**.

ComponentA

```
...
<cc:implentation>
   <my:componentB>
        <f:attribute name="myAttr" value="The attribute value"/>
   </my:componentB>
</cc:implementation>
```

ComponentB

```
<cc:interface>
    ...
    <cc:attribute name="myAttr"/>
</cc:attribute>

<cc:implementation>
    <my:input name="input1"/>
    <my:input name="input2">
        <f:attribute name="input1Value" value="#{cc.attrs.myAttr}"/>
        <f:validator validatorId="myInputValidator" for="inputText"/>      
    </my:input>
</cc:implementation>
```